# Trigger events every time users touch-scroll through 40px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `touchmove` function that checks how many pixels were scrolled by user.  It is hooked up to a custom slider I made that has 5 steps with 40 px between each step, hence I want to go to the next step when 40px are scrolled, I tried `amountScrolled % 40 == 0` but the issue here is that sometimes numbers are skipped if the user's finger drags quite quickly, therefore I'm not guaranteed to see numbers like 40 or 80 that I expect, so I tried `absoluteTouchDistance > 40 || absoluteTouchDistance > 80 || ...` , issue here is that after that first condition, it gets executed all the time, whereas I want it to execute next if number was 80 or 120 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should get you going:

```
steps = math.floor(absoluteTouchDistance/40);
```

now you can conveniently check if `steps` has changed, and react accordingly.